# What's wrong with my "solve" function in my C++ assignment?

Tags: c++

I have an assignment from my C++ course that is an interpretation of the Tri Wizard Tournament maze challenge from Harry Potter. The instructions for the assignment are here:  http://www.cs.rhodes.edu/~kirlinp/courses/cs2/s17/proj/proj5/

Currently I am struggling with my solve function. The movements keep going out of the range, ex: numbers larger than the number of rows / cols or negative numbers. I'm also getting infinite output, like the movements continue forever until it is terminated because of being identified as an infinite loop.

If you would please look over my code / the assignment, I would be extremely appreciative. I feel like I have most of the code correct but I have problems that I don't know how to fix myself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

vector<string> read_function(string file);
string solve(vector<string> maze, int &row, int &col, int &numcalls);
void find_start(vector<string> maze, int &row, int &col);
void print_state();
vector<string> maze;
string s;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter a file name: " << endl;
    string file;
    cin >> file;

    vector<string> test = read_function(file);

    print_state();

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    int numcalls = 0;

    find_start(maze, row, col);
    cout << "start is: " << row << "," << col << endl;

    string solution = solve(maze, row, col, numcalls);
    cout << solution << endl;
    cout << "Number of steps: " << numcalls << endl;

    print_state();

    return 0;
}

vector<string> read_function(string file) {
    ifstream infile; // Input file stream
    infile.open(file);

    while (getline(infile, s)) //
    {
        //infile >> s;
        maze.push_back(s);
    }
    infile.close();
    return maze;
}


void print_state(){
    for (int i = 0; i < maze.size(); i++){
        cout << maze[i] << endl;
    }
}

string solve(vector<string> maze, int &row, int &col, int &numcalls){
    numcalls += 1;
    cout << row << "," << col << endl;
    maze[row][col] = 'o';
    if (maze[row][col] == 'C') {
        return " C ";
    }
    if (row>=0 && maze[row-1][col] != '#' && maze[row-1][col] != 'o'&& maze[row-1][col] != ' '){    // MOVE NORTH Y/N
        row --;
        string answer = solve(maze, row, col, numcalls);
        if (answer != "X"){
            return "N"+answer;
        }
    }
    if (maze[row+1][col] != '#' && maze[row+1][col] != 'o' && maze[row+1]
[col] != ' '){   // MOVE SOUTH Y/N
        row ++;
        string answer = solve(maze, row, col, numcalls);
        if (answer != "X"){
             return "S"+answer;
        }
    }
    if (maze[row][col+1] != '#' && maze[row][col+1] != 'o' && maze[row]
[col+1] != ' '){   // MOVE EAST Y/N
        col ++;
        string answer = solve(maze, row, col, numcalls);
        if (answer != "X"){
            return "E"+answer;
        }
    }
    if (maze[row][col-1] != '#' && maze[row][col-1] != 'o' && maze[row][col-
1] != ' '){        // MOVE WEST Y/N
        col --;
        string answer = solve(maze, row, col, numcalls);
        if (answer != "X"){
            return "W"+answer;
        }
    }
    else{
        maze[row][col] = '.';
    }
    return "X";
}**

void find_start(vector<string> maze, int &row, int &col){

   for (int i = 0; i < maze.size(); i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < maze[i].size(); j++){
           if (maze[i][j] == 'H'){
               row = i;
               col = j;
           }
        }

   }
}
```

Comment: So, just for starters: Are you expecting your changes to `maze` to be preserved after the function returns? You're passing `maze` in by value, so the mutations only last until the function returns; the caller value is unchanged. This applies to your recursive case as well; the changes you've made so far are sent to the recursive call, but changes made within it aren't preserved. Basically, it's extremely unusual to receive a `vector` by value; usually you receive it by `const` reference (when not changing it) or by reference (when implicitly changing the caller's variable is intended).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I totally missed that, thank you! I went through and made maze be passed by reference (&, you know...).  There's still something else making the output continue to be huge numbers or negatives, which it shouldn't be.... maybe in my if statements? I've been tweaking those to see if I can find something that works, but no luck yet.

Comment: What stops row and col from going outside the bounds of the maze?

Comment: @RetiredNinja that's something I've been trying to figure out how to write, I haven't been able to fix the if statements to constrain row and col that way

Comment: I notice you're using `col - 1` without checking if `col` is greater than 0 in `solve()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several bound checks missing, as well as return string value of path would always return 'X'.

- Bound checks - if you access array, make sure you have valid indexes - in your case every condition of col+-1/row+-1 in array access, need to be checked first (see my source sample). This is pretty much you asked for
- Your breadcrumb marker was overwriting your 'C' mark.
- Changed passing or row/col indexes by value to recursive method calls - it is easier to keep track of its value
- any_direction bool variable resolves wheter to dump complete path (final method call) or just finish by 'X'

Your fixed source of solve() method:

```
    string solve(vector<string>& maze, int row, int col, int &numcalls) {

    numcalls += 1;
    cout << row << "," << col << endl;
    string answer;

    bool any_direction = false;

    if (maze[row][col] == 'C') {
        return " C ";
    }
    maze[row][col] = 'o';

    if (row > 0 && maze[row-1][col] != '#' && maze[row-1][col] != 'o'&& maze[row-1][col] != ' '){    // MOVE NORTH Y/N
        //row--;
        answer = solve(maze, row-1, col, numcalls);
        if (answer != "X"){
            any_direction = true;
            return "N"+answer;
        }
    }
    if (row < (maze.size()-1) && maze[row+1][col] != '#' && maze[row+1][col] != 'o' && maze[row+1][col] != ' '){   // MOVE SOUTH Y/N
        //row++;
        answer = solve(maze, row+1, col, numcalls);
        if (answer != "X"){
            any_direction = true;
            return "S"+answer;
        }

    }
    if (col < (maze[row].size()-1) && maze[row][col+1] != '#' && maze[row][col+1] != 'o' && maze[row][col+1] != ' '){   // MOVE EAST Y/N
        //col++;
        answer = solve(maze, row, col+1, numcalls);
        if (answer != "X"){
            any_direction = true;
            return "E"+answer;
        }
    }
    if (col > 0 && maze[row][col-1] != '#' && maze[row][col-1] != 'o' && maze[row][col-1] != ' '){        // MOVE WEST Y/N
        //col--;
        answer = solve(maze, row, col-1, numcalls);
        if (answer != "X"){
            any_direction = true;
            return "W"+answer;
        }
    }

    if(!any_direction) {
        maze[row][col] = '.';
        return "X";
    }
    return answer;
}
```

This solution is not complete for your task, but hope it will help you finish it and understand recursion a little bit better. Enjoy your C++ studies!